# Fresh install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on NUC10 -- Either No Sound or no Shutdown

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, shutdown, hdmi

I have a bunch of NUC10s I am using for a project (both i3 and i5s) onto which I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. These NUC models have no audio jack and rely on HDMI for sound.  But I have no sound.  I performed the same install on NUC7s and had sound over HDMI without incident.

After googling for 2 days, I think I've tried every suggested fix from this site and many others. The only success I've had is to upgrade the kernel from 5.13.  I've tried 5.14,5.15, and 5.16.  Sound works fine on all three.  However, once I upgrade the kernel I cannot shutdown or reboot.  It hangs at [OK] Reached target Reboot (or Shutdown). I tried using an older kernel - 5.4 - and applying numerous edit recommendations to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf -- still no sound.

Just as a test, I installed SuSE 15.3 which worked fine (which for various reasons I cannot use for this project).  I also tried Debian 11, on which the sound fails as well.  So honestly I'm out of ideas.  If push comes to shove, I'll choose sound over shutdown, but I really don't want to.

I'm open to ideas on both the sound and booting fronts if anybody has any solid fixes for either.  My current test box is a BXNUC103FNKN2.

Additional Requested Information:

```
$ pactl list sinks
    Sink #0
        State: RUNNING
        Name: auto_null
        Description: Dummy Output
        Driver: module-null-sink.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 14
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: auto_null.monitor
        Latency: 80 usec, configured 500 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS
        Properties:
                device.description = "Dummy Output"
                device.class = "abstract"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
        Formats:
                pcm
```

Comment: HDMI is part of the "graphics" card , so we need to know if pulseaudio can see it. Could you paste the output of `pactl list sinks` into your question?

Comment: So no sink is found. Probably also no card. You might be able to get the correct driver and compile it against your working kernel. [This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=225346) thread might help you...

Comment: i can offer that when I could not shutdown or reboot, all i could do to fix it was do my install in legacy mode(bios) on an older different pc. Then move that drive back into the newer computer and it worked fine. I never figured out the real problem, all my research was pointing to a problem with ACPI, but everything I looked up concerning that did not work... So I stayed with my workaround. Maybe this will help with 1 of the problems........  I just looked up "NUC 10"... I was installing on something similar, mine was a dell wyse 7010 thin client (i had a bunch of them too)